# How do I fix "positional parameter cannot be found that accepts "+""?

Tags: powershell, scripting

So I have this task in which I have to read a file.
Then count how many times every word in the file occurs.
After that every single word must be written to an additional file with behind that specific word the number of how many times it occurs.

I have some code already but I'm running into errors with everything I try,
I'm new to this and I don't understand a lot of the error messages.

```
Function AnalyseTo-Doc
{
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Pad )
    New-Item C:\destination.txt -ItemType file
    $destination = "C:\destination.txt"
    $filecontents = get-content $Pad | Out-String

    foreach($hit in $filecontents)
    {
        #$tempWoord = $hit | Convert-String
        $lengte = $hit.Length
        if($lengte -ge 4)
        {
            $hits = get-content $Pad | Out-String
            if($hits -notcontains $hit)
            {
                Add-Content $destination $hit + $hit.LineNumber + '`n'
            }
            elseif($hits -contains $hit)
            {
                Add-Content $destination $hit + $hit.LineNumber + '`n'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as said above, what this has to do is:

1. It has to read the file properly.
2. It has to know if words are over 4 characters. If they are, they must be counted
3. Every word of over 4 chars must be counted.
4. Last, every single word must be written to an additional file where it says the word itself and a count behind it.

By count I mean: how many times it appears in the text file

PS: We're testing with `.txt` files

Comment: How are you treating contractions? Is `What's` treated as `what is` or is `what's` the word you want counted? Same question goes for hyphenated words, i.e. are they two words or one?

Comment: it looks like this `$hit + $hit.LineNumber + '`n'` is the source of your error. PoSh errors USUALLY include the line number & the text, so you REALLY otta include that info. ///// as for WHY the error happens  - you are giving the cmdlet _six_ items and two of those are `+` signs. the fix = convert those items to a single item - a string.

Comment: Let's say "what's" will be treated as "what is". I'm not sure what the easiest approach is, if it's easier the other way it's good as well.

Comment: So the $hit should be converted to a string? Isn't this the correct way to do it (    $tempWoord = $hit | Convert-String)? Cause when i do it this way it's giving me a "nullreferenceexception" error. @Lee_Dailey

Comment: @NDC - no ... that whole bunch of text needs to be ONE THING. build a string that holds that data and then use THAT as the value in the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question already has an answer, but if we are only counting consecutive alpha characters as words and you want the total count of those words, this should work provided there are no character exceptions. The post in the question doesn't seem to actually count words.

```
Function AnalyseTo-Doc
{
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Pad )

    New-Item C:\destination.txt -ItemType file
    $destination = "C:\destination.txt"
    $filecontents = Get-Content $Pad -Raw

    $words = ($filecontents | Select-String -Pattern "\b[A-Za-z]{4,}\b" -AllMatches).Matches.Value
    $words | Group-Object -NoElement | Foreach-Object {
        ("{0},{1}" -f $_.Count,$_.Name) | Add-Content -Path $destination
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much, this is exactly as i needed it to be!!!! You made my day good sir :)

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: As the question is `How do i fix “positional parameter cannot be found that accepts ”+“`, let me answer exactly that one. The answer below doesn't address other issues which might appear once you fix the below.

---

What you should see in your error message is something like:

```
PS C:\SO\56526906> Add-Content 'destination.txt' $a + $b + $c
Add-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Content 'destination.txt' $a + $b + $c
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
```

Which points you directly to the line where the error occurs. In that case, it's because you're giving the following parameters to `Add-Content`:

```
$destination
$hit
+
$hit.LineNumber
+
'`n'
```

While you should add only destination and content. Your invocation of `Add-Content` should look like this:

```
Add-Content $destination "$hit $($hit.LineNumber)"
```

Please notice that you don't need to add `n after `Add-Content` as newlines will be added automatically.